# Why does Python have both "match" and "search"?

Tags: python

Python's `re.match` does exactly the same thing as `re.search` except it appends a `\A` at the beginning of the pattern (meaning match only at the beginning of the string).  What is the point of having a whole other method just to do that?

Comment: The same point of having a `print()` as well as a `println()`.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: Python has no `println()`.

Comment: Regardless of language it's the same reason. One is able to do everything the other can do but isn't as nice to look at when doing it.

Comment: Actually, this is a very valid question considering Python comes alongside the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), which among others, states: *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.* The OP is correct in wondering why for such a trivial task, there are two *not-so-obvious* ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Python documentation:

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).
>
> For example:
>
> > > > re.match("c", "abcdef")    # No match
> > > >         re.search("c", "abcdef")   # Match <_sre.SRE_Match object at ...> Regular expressions beginning with '^' can be used with search() to
> > > >         restrict the match at the beginning of the string:
> > > >
> > > > re.match("c", "abcdef")    # No match
> > > >         re.search("^c", "abcdef")  # No match
> > > >         re.search("^a", "abcdef")  # Match <_sre.SRE_Match object at ...> Note however that in MULTILINE mode match() only matches at the
> > > >         beginning of the string, whereas using search() with a regular
> > > >         expression beginning with '^' will match at the beginning of each
> > > >         line.
> > > >
> > > > re.match('X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # No match
> > > >         re.search('^X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # Match <_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>

As for the ‘why’ both exist, it could be said that one function is used over the other as a matter of convenience and to make the intention of the code clearer.

Comment: @JoelFan - if you find my response answers your question, please accept it. If not, please let me know if I need to elaborate further.

Answer (score 0):

Both match and search are operations for regular expressions. Match works differently when you use "^":"^" at the beginning of the expression matches only  when the pattern appears at the start of the string (regardless of mode.) Search works like search in Perl.

As for the why, as an example I would use search to find an expression when I'm not sure if it exists, and match when I needed to see that exact string, perhaps for data modification.

Comment: This answer is wrong: it confuses the two methods.

The carat (``^``) makes no difference in ``match``, it only affects ``search``.  Prefixing the pattern with ``^`` and using ``search`` is effectively the same as using ``match``.


Also, there is a comparison to Perl, which neither was asked about nor helps clarify the answer for anyone unfamiliar with Perl's search function.